# How to implement a rich text editor in a view (PyQt/PySide/Qt)?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

**Short version**

I have a `QTreeView` and want users to have fine-grained control over the appearance of text, giving them rich-text formatting options. I already have it so entire items can be selected for formatting (e.g., as bold), but I need more flexibility. For instance, the user must be able to highlight *parts* of an item's text and embolden it.

Note I am using `QStandardItemModel` (see SSCCE below).

**Detailed version**

To embolden an entire item is simple:

```
itemFont = item.font()
itemFont.setBold(True)
item.setFont(itemFont)
```

Unfortunately, my users need more fine-grained control, so instead of

> **Hi how are you?**

they should be able to select just the first word using their mouse and make that item's text appear as:

> **Hi** how are you?

Two options I am considering are:

1. **setIndexWidget**

   In each cell where I need this functionality, display it as a `QTextEdit` widget using `setIndexWidget`, something like was done here: 
   [To set widgets on children items on QTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283677/to-set-widgets-on-children-items-on-qtreeview). Then I could use the standard tools for rich text editing in each cell.
2. **Custom delegate**

   Use a custom delegate to paint each item where I need this functionality, something like what was applied here:
   [How to make item view render rich (html) text in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956542/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-qt)

Note unlike that question, I'm not just asking how to render rich text, but how to let the user *select text* and have it rendered as rich text on a fine-grained scale.

**SSCCE**

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MainTree(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tree, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose) 
        self.setCentralWidget(tree)
        self.createStatusBar()
        self.createBoldAction()
        self.createToolbar()

    def createStatusBar(self):                          
        self.status = self.statusBar()
        self.status.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        self.status.showMessage("Ready")

    def createToolbar(self):
        self.textToolbar = self.addToolBar("Text actions")
        self.textToolbar.addAction(self.boldTextAction)

    def createBoldAction(self):
        self.boldTextAction = QtGui.QAction("Bold", self)
        self.boldTextAction.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("boldText.png"))
        self.boldTextAction.triggered.connect(self.emboldenText)
        self.boldTextAction.setStatusTip("Make selected text bold")

    def emboldenText(self):
        print "Make selected text bold...How do I do this?"


class SimpleTree(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):    
        QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Title', 'Summary'])
        rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title0'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary0')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title00'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary00')]
        rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00)          
        self.setModel(model)
        self.expandAll()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myTree = SimpleTree()
    #myTree.show()
    myMainTree = MainTree(myTree)
    myMainTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reasonable way to do this is using your option 2: create a custom delegate. Yours is pretty much the exact kind of situation delegates are made for: use `createEditor` to create a custom editor (such as a spin box, or rich text editor, or whatever), and also implement a `paint` method that lets you control exactly how the data will look once it is entered. While there might be other ways to do it, they are almost guaranteed to be worse than using a delegate.

Hence, to get this to work, you'll need to reimplement `paint` as well as `createEditor` for a `QStyledItemDelegate`.

Unfortunately, for implementing `createEditor`, Qt doesn't provide a native rich text line editor (that is, there is nothing like `QLineEdit` for rich text). Luckily, Mark Summerfield actually wrote such a function in Chapter 13 of his book on PyQt, so I've adopted that into a fully working example below, which includes a tree view in a main window, with the ability to toggle the text properties using the toolbar or a context (right-click) menu or keyboard shortcuts when the editor is open.

[image]

---

**Relevant posts**

I directly got help implementing many of these features in the following threads:

- [Vertically center item's text using a delegate (PySide/Qt/PyQt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909349/vertically-center-views-text-using-a-delegate-pyside-qt-pyqt)
- [Connect action in QMainWindow with method of view's delegate (PySide/Qt/PyQt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924114/connect-action-in-qmainwindow-with-method-of-views-delegate-pyside-qt-pyqt)
- [How to vertically center a single-line in a QTextEdit instance (PySide/PyQt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941367/how-to-vertically-align-text-in-qtextedit-pyside-pyqt)

---

**The icons**

Here are the images used in the toolbar:

[image: boldText.png]
[image: italicText.png]
[image: strikeoutText.png]
[image: underlineText.png]

---

**The Code**

Here is the code. I apologize for the size, but it includes so many things that might be useful for those learning delegates (as the OP obviously is) that I decided not to edit it down:

```
import sys
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape as escape
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class MainTree(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tree, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose) 
        self.setCentralWidget(tree)
        self.createStatusBar()
        self.createActions()
        self.createToolbar()
        self.tree = tree
        self.setGeometry(500,150,400,300)

    def createStatusBar(self):                          
        self.status = self.statusBar()
        self.status.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        self.status.showMessage("Ready")

    def createActions(self):
        '''Create all actions to be used in toolbars/menus: calls createAction()'''
        self.boldTextAction = self.createAction("&Bold",
                shortcut = QtGui.QKeySequence.Bold, iconName = "boldText", tip = "Embolden",
                status = "Toggle bold", disabled = True)              
        self.italicTextAction = self.createAction("&Italic",
                shortcut = QtGui.QKeySequence.Italic, iconName = "italicText", tip = "Italicize",
                status = "Toggle italics", disabled = True)
        self.underlineTextAction = self.createAction("&Underline",
                shortcut = QtGui.QKeySequence.Underline, iconName = "underlineText", tip = "Underline",
                status = "Toggle underline", disabled = True)   
        self.strikeoutTextAction = self.createAction("Stri&keout",
                shortcut = QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+K"), iconName = "strikeoutText", tip = "Strikeout",
                status = "Toggle strikeout", disabled = True)                

    def createAction(self, text, slot = None, shortcut = None, iconName = None,
                     tip = None, status = None, disabled = False):
        '''Creates each individual action'''
        action = QtGui.QAction(text, self)
        if iconName is not None:
            action.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("{0}.png".format(iconName)))
        if shortcut is not None:
            action.setShortcut(shortcut)
        if tip is not None:
            action.setToolTip(tip)
        if status is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status)
        if slot is not None:
            action.triggered.connect(slot)
        if disabled:
            action.setDisabled(True)
        return action 

    def createToolbar(self):
        self.textToolbar = self.addToolBar("Text actions")
        self.textToolbar.addAction(self.boldTextAction)
        self.textToolbar.addAction(self.underlineTextAction)
        self.textToolbar.addAction(self.italicTextAction)
        self.textToolbar.addAction(self.strikeoutTextAction)

class HtmlTree(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):    
        QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Task', 'Description'])
        self.rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Sneeze'), QtGui.QStandardItem('You have been blocked up')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Tickle nose'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Key first step')]
        item1 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Get a job'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Do not blow it')]
        item01 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Call temp agency'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Maybe they will be kind')]
        self.rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00) 
        self.rootItem.appendRow(item1)
        item1[0].appendRow(item01)
        self.setModel(model)
        self.expandAll()
        self.setItemDelegate(HtmlPainter(self))
        self.resizeColumnToContents(0)
        self.resizeColumnToContents(1)
        #print "unoiform row heights? ", self.uniformRowHeights()

class HtmlPainter(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        print "delegate parent: ", parent, parent.metaObject().className()
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1 or index.column() == 0: 
            text = index.model().data(index) 
            palette = QtGui.QApplication.palette()
            document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
            document.setDefaultFont(option.font)
            #Set text (color depends on whether selected)
            if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:  
                displayString = "<font color={0}>{1}</font>".format(palette.highlightedText().color().name(), text) 
                document.setHtml(displayString)
            else:
                document.setHtml(text)
            #Set background color
            bgColor = palette.highlight().color() if (option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected)\
                     else palette.base().color()
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, bgColor)
            document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
            offset_y = (option.rect.height() - document.size().height())/2
            painter.translate(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y() + offset_y) 
            document.drawContents(painter)
            painter.restore()
        else:
            QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)          

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        rowHeight = 18
        text = index.model().data(index)
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        document.setDefaultFont(option.font)
        document.setHtml(text)
        return QtCore.QSize(document.idealWidth() + 5,  rowHeight) #fm.height())

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            editor = RichTextLineEdit(option, parent)
            editor.returnPressed.connect(self.commitAndCloseEditor) 
            editor.mainWindow = parent.window()
            self.setConnections(editor.mainWindow, editor)
            self.enableActions(editor.mainWindow)
            return editor
        else:
            return QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option,
                                                    index)

    def setConnections(self, mainWindow, editor):
            '''Create connections for font toggle actions when editor is created'''
            mainWindow.boldTextAction.triggered.connect(editor.toggleBold)
            mainWindow.underlineTextAction.triggered.connect(editor.toggleUnderline)
            mainWindow.italicTextAction.triggered.connect(editor.toggleItalic)
            mainWindow.strikeoutTextAction.triggered.connect(editor.toggleStrikeout)

    def enableActions(self, mainWindow):
            mainWindow.boldTextAction.setEnabled(True)
            mainWindow.underlineTextAction.setEnabled(True)
            mainWindow.italicTextAction.setEnabled(True)
            mainWindow.strikeoutTextAction.setEnabled(True)

    def disableActions(self, mainWindow):
            mainWindow.boldTextAction.setDisabled(True)
            mainWindow.underlineTextAction.setDisabled(True)
            mainWindow.italicTextAction.setDisabled(True)
            mainWindow.strikeoutTextAction.setDisabled(True)  

    def commitAndCloseEditor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        if isinstance(editor, (QtGui.QTextEdit, QtGui.QLineEdit)):
            self.commitData.emit(editor)
            self.closeEditor.emit(editor, QtGui.QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):        
        if index.column() == 1:
            self.disableActions(editor.mainWindow)
            model.setData(index, editor.toSimpleHtml())
        else:
            QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.setModelData(self, editor, model, index)



class RichTextLineEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    '''Single line editor invoked by delegate'''
    (Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut) = range(4)
    returnPressed = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self,  option, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTextEdit.__init__(self,  parent)
        self.setLineWrapMode(QtGui.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        #Following lines set it so text is centered in editor        
        fontMetrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())       
        margin = 2
        self.document().setDocumentMargin(margin)
        height = fontMetrics.height() + (margin + self.frameWidth()) * 2
        self.setFixedHeight(height)
        self.setToolTip("Right click for text effect menu.")

    def toggleBold(self):
        self.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Normal
                if self.fontWeight() > QtGui.QFont.Normal else QtGui.QFont.Bold)

    def toggleItalic(self):
        self.setFontItalic(not self.fontItalic())     

    def toggleUnderline(self):
        self.setFontUnderline(not self.fontUnderline())


    def toggleStrikeout(self): 
        #Adapted from: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/developing-a-pyqt-text-editor-part-2/145
        #https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTextCharFormat.html
        # Grab the text's format
        textFormat = self.currentCharFormat()
        # Change the fontStrikeOut property to its opposite
        textFormat.setFontStrikeOut(not textFormat.fontStrikeOut())  
        # Apply the new format
        self.setCurrentCharFormat(textFormat)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        '''
        Context menu for controlling text
        '''
        textFormat = self.currentCharFormat()
        menu = QtGui.QMenu("Text Effects")
        for text, shortcut, data, checked in (
                ("&Bold", "Ctrl+B", RichTextLineEdit.Bold,
                 self.fontWeight() > QtGui.QFont.Normal),
                ("&Italic", "Ctrl+I", RichTextLineEdit.Italic,
                 self.fontItalic()),
                ("Stri&keout", "Ctrl+K", RichTextLineEdit.StrikeOut,
                 textFormat.fontStrikeOut()),
                ("&Underline", "Ctrl+U", RichTextLineEdit.Underline,
                 self.fontUnderline())):
            action = menu.addAction(text, self.setTextEffect)
            if shortcut is not None:
                action.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(shortcut))
            action.setData(data)
            action.setCheckable(True)
            action.setChecked(checked)
        self.ensureCursorVisible()
        menu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(
                   self.cursorRect().center()))

    def setTextEffect(self):
        '''Called by context menu'''
        action = self.sender()
        if action is not None and isinstance(action, QtGui.QAction):
            what = int(action.data())
            if what == RichTextLineEdit.Bold:
                self.toggleBold()
                return
            if what == RichTextLineEdit.Italic:
                self.toggleItalic()
                return
            if what == RichTextLineEdit.Underline:
                self.toggleUnderline()
                return
            format = self.currentCharFormat()
            if what == RichTextLineEdit.StrikeOut:
                format.setFontStrikeOut(not format.fontStrikeOut())
            self.mergeCurrentCharFormat(format)     

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        '''
        Handles all keyboard shortcuts, and stops retun from returning newline
        '''
        if event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
            handled = False
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_B:
                self.toggleBold()
                handled = True
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_I:
                self.toggleItalic()
                handled = True
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_U:
                self.toggleUnderline()
                handled = True
            if handled:
                event.accept()
                return
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return):
            self.returnPressed.emit()
            event.accept()
        else:
            QtGui.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def toSimpleHtml(self):
        html = ""
        block = self.document().begin()
        while block.isValid():
            iterator = block.begin()
            while iterator != block.end():
                fragment = iterator.fragment()
                if fragment.isValid():
                    format = fragment.charFormat()
                    text = escape(fragment.text())
                    if format.fontUnderline():
                        text = "<u>{}</u>".format(text)
                    if format.fontItalic():
                        text = "<i>{}</i>".format(text)
                    if format.fontWeight() > QtGui.QFont.Normal:
                        text = "<b>{}</b>".format(text)
                    if format.fontStrikeOut():
                        text = "<s>{}</s>".format(text)
                    html += text
                iterator += 1
            block = block.next()
        return html


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myTree = HtmlTree()    #myTree.show()
    myMainTree = MainTree(myTree)
    myMainTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I have used a similar paint method as you under the HtmlPainter delegate. However I've never been able to get back the dotted box that surrounds the cell when selected. Have you figured out a way to re-implement this?

Comment: @RXander I haven't ever played with that, but in the `QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected` bit of the delegate you should be able to play with the fill/outline of the `QRect`. If you want to see how they do it in the default views, see the followig post about how to start exploring (though beware, exploring mechanics of default delegates is only for the brave of heart, it just about killed me :) ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990029/what-are-the-mechanics-of-the-default-delegate-for-item-views-in-qt

Comment: thanks for your comment. I figured it out by implementing `QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)` using the Qpen and QBrush painter methods. A lot of your posts have been helpful. Yeah I've found perusing the pyqt sourceforge information much more useful than the raw code for now. A comprehensive book on using styles in pyqt/pyside would definitely help for beginners, but I haven't found one. But Rapid Gui Programming with python and qt has also been helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @RXander At this point I've pretty much given up on PyQt I spent more time trying to figure out how to do what I thought should be really simple stuff than actually productive coding. There's a year of my life I'll never get back. :) Glad some of my posts helped, I put tons of time into them.