# Vertically center item's text using a delegate (PySide/Qt/PyQt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a custom delegate for a `QTableView` that allows for the display/editing of html strings (using a `QTextDocument`). There is a SSCCE below.

Unfortunately, when I display the text using `paint()`, it is not vertically centered, but seems to top align. For instance, if I apply the delegate to the second column, but not the first, the table looks like this:

[image: the problem]

My search hasn't revealed anything on how to fix this from within the delegate in a principled way. Manually adding 5 to `option.rect.y()` works on my computer, but I don't consider that principled.

Is there some way to center the text vertically?

**SSCCE**

```
from PySide import QtGui
import sys

class HtmlTable(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):    
        QtGui.QTableView.__init__(self)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Title', 'Summary'])
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Infinite Jest'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Hello, <i>Hal</i>')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Hamlet'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Best served <b>cold</b>')]
        model.appendRow(item0)
        model.appendRow(item00)          
        self.setModel(model)
        self.setItemDelegate(HtmlPainter(self))

class HtmlPainter(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1: 
            text = index.model().data(index) #default role is display
            palette = QtGui.QApplication.palette()
            document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
            document.setDefaultFont(option.font)
            #Set text (color depends on whether selected)
            if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:  
                displayString = "<font color={0}>{1}</font>".format(palette.highlightedText().color().name(), text) 
                document.setHtml(displayString)
            else:
                document.setHtml(text)
            #Set background color
            bgColor = palette.highlight().color() if (option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected)\
                     else palette.base().color()
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, bgColor)
            painter.translate(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y())  #If I add +5 it works
            document.drawContents(painter)
            painter.restore()
        else:
            QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)          


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myTable = HtmlTable()
    myTable.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set document's width using `QTextDocument::setTextWidth`. This allows you to determine text height and use it to calculate offset:

```
document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
offset_y = (option.rect.height() - document.size().height())/2
painter.translate(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y() + offset_y) 
document.drawContents(painter)
```

Setting text width is also necessary because otherwise the text would not be wrapped when column is not wide enough.

You might want to reimplement `sizeHint` to calculate preferred width and height based on document size.

Comment: Voila! Yes, I have a full example with `sizeHint` implemented. I just wanted to whittle my SSCCE down to the essential nub. I'll have to check to see if I did it right, now that this problem seems fixed. :)