# Connect action in QMainWindow with method of view's delegate (PySide/Qt/PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, oop, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QTreeView` displaying data from a `QStandardItemModel`. One of the columns of the tree is displayed with a delegate that lets the user edit and display rich text. Below is a SSCCE that limits the editing to bold (with keyboard shortcut).

When the user is editing one of the items, how can I set it up so that in addition to toggling boldness with keyboard shortcut (CTRL-B), the user can also toggle it using the toolbar icon?

[image]

Thus far, the keyboard shortcut works great (you can double click, edit text, and CTRL-B will toggle bold). However, I haven't figured out how to connect the bold button in the toolbar to the appropriate slot:

```
    self.boldTextAction.triggered.connect(self.emboldenText)
```

where I have this just sitting there doing nothing:

```
def emboldenText(self):
    print "Make selected text bold...How do I do this?"
```

Things would be easy if the main window's central widget was the text editor: I could directly invoke the text editor's toggle bold method. Unfortunately, the text editor is only generated transiently by the tree view's delegate when the user double-clicks to start editing the tree.

That is,  we have this complicated relationship:

> QMainWindow -> QTreeView -> Delegate.CreateEditor ->
>   QTextEdit.toggleBold()

How do I access toggleBold() from within the main window for use by the toolbar action, especially given that the editor is only created temporarily when opened by the user?

I realize this may not be a PySide/Qt question as much as a Python/OOP question, so I've included additional potentially relevant tags. Any help with improving my word choice/jargon would be appreciated too.

**SSCCE**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import platform
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class MainTree(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tree, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose) 
        self.setCentralWidget(tree)
        self.createStatusBar()
        self.createBoldAction()
        self.createToolbar()
        self.tree = tree
        #self.htmlDelegate = self.tree.itemDelegateForColumn(1)

    def createStatusBar(self):                          
        self.status = self.statusBar()
        self.status.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        self.status.showMessage("In editor, keyboard to toggle bold")

    def createToolbar(self):
        self.textToolbar = self.addToolBar("Text actions")
        self.textToolbar.addAction(self.boldTextAction)

    def createBoldAction(self):
        self.boldTextAction = QtGui.QAction("Bold", self)
        self.boldTextAction.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("boldText.png"))
        self.boldTextAction.triggered.connect(self.emboldenText)
        self.boldTextAction.setStatusTip("Make selected text bold")

    def emboldenText(self):
        print "Make selected text bold...How do I do this? It's stuck in RichTextLineEdit"

class HtmlTree(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):    
        QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Task', 'Priority'])
        rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Sneeze'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Low')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Tickle nose'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Low')]
        item1 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Get a job'), QtGui.QStandardItem('<b>High</b>')]
        item01 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Call temp agency'), QtGui.QStandardItem('<b>Extremely</b> <i>high</i>')]
        rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00) 
        rootItem.appendRow(item1)
        item1[0].appendRow(item01)
        self.setModel(model)
        self.expandAll()
        self.resizeColumnToContents(0)
        self.setToolTip("Use keyboard to toggle bold")
        self.setItemDelegate(HtmlPainter(self))

class HtmlPainter(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1: 
            text = index.model().data(index) #default role is display (for edit consider fixing Valign prob)
            palette = QtGui.QApplication.palette()
            document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
            document.setDefaultFont(option.font)
            #Set text (color depends on whether selected)
            if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:  
                displayString = "<font color={0}>{1}</font>".format(palette.highlightedText().color().name(), text) 
                document.setHtml(displayString)
            else:
                document.setHtml(text)
            #Set background color
            bgColor = palette.highlight().color() if (option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected)\
                     else palette.base().color()
            painter.save()

            painter.fillRect(option.rect, bgColor)
            document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
            offset_y = (option.rect.height() - document.size().height())/2
            painter.translate(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y() + offset_y) 
            document.drawContents(painter)
            painter.restore()
        else:
            QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)          

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        fm = option.fontMetrics
        if index.column() == 1:
            text = index.model().data(index)
            document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
            document.setDefaultFont(option.font)
            document.setHtml(text)
            return QtCore.QSize(document.idealWidth() + 5, fm.height())
        return QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint(self, option, index)


    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            editor = RichTextLineEdit(parent)
            editor.returnPressed.connect(self.commitAndCloseEditor)
            return editor
        else:
            return QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option,
                                                    index)

    def commitAndCloseEditor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        if isinstance(editor, (QtGui.QTextEdit, QtGui.QLineEdit)):
            self.commitData.emit(editor)
            self.closeEditor.emit(editor, QtGui.QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)


class RichTextLineEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):

    returnPressed = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLineWrapMode(QtGui.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        fontMetrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())
        h = int(fontMetrics.height() * (1.4 if platform.system() == "Windows"
                                   else 1.2))
        self.setMinimumHeight(h)
        self.setMaximumHeight(int(h * 1.2))
        self.setToolTip("Press <b>Ctrl+b</b> to toggle bold")

    def toggleBold(self):
        self.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Normal
                if self.fontWeight() > QtGui.QFont.Normal else QtGui.QFont.Bold)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(self.document().idealWidth() + 5,
                     self.maximumHeight())

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())
        return QtCore.QSize(fm.width("WWWW"), self.minimumHeight())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        '''This just handles all keyboard shortcuts, and stops retun from returning'''
        if event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
            handled = False
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_B:
                self.toggleBold()
                handled = True
            if handled:
                event.accept()
                return
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return):
            self.returnPressed.emit()
            event.accept()
        else:
            QtGui.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myTree = HtmlTree()
    #myTree.show()
    myMainTree = MainTree(myTree)
    myMainTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note for those that want the Full Tree Experience, with the button in the toolbar, here it is you can put it in the same folder as the script (change the name to `boldText.png`:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but your code didn't seem to run - it just finished with no window appearing - when I ran it.  Anyway I have a possible answer below.

Comment: I thought it might make sense to create a single editor and use that each time createEditor is called.  That could work but I had second thoughts when I noticed that you want the Bold button to disappear when there is no editor.

Comment: It should run. E.g., it works for me when I cut/paste/run in all my machines. Perhaps those in Linux need to add `#!/usr/bin/env python` : I just added it. Also, I do *not* want the bold button to disappear when there is no editor. At some future point I may grey it out when there is no editor active, but that is an ornament that can wait for now. Also, I just added the 'boldText.png' button for toolbar so you can get that to appear if you want.

Comment: This seems to be a non-question. If you need to have shared access to some objects, then you will have to provide shared access for those objects (e.g. put them in a globally accessible namespace, such as a module).

Comment: @ekhumoro See last para before SSCCE: if this isn't a pure PySide question, it is still a question! My question is since these text editors are only transiently in existence, created when needed by the delegate, how do I pull it off? It's not like there is some generic class I can refer to. Also, you can see in commented out line in initialization of qmainwindow where I was trying to go, but got stuck.

Comment: @neuronet. It's a non-question, in that you've already identified exactly what the issue is. And as I said in my previous comment, the solution is to provide some kind of shared access for the object (i.e. the `boldTextAction`, in this specific case).

Comment: @ekhumoro ok I think I was thinking about it wrong I'll try sending along some objects directly in to the delegate as parameters.....I was hoping to take care of it all within QMainWindow (by analogy with the more standard text editors where it is easy to just connect to the central widget's methods). Perhaps that is what I was getting tripped up on...Will work on this and post answer if I figure it out tonight. For some reason that felt "non-modular" and didn't even want to go there, but seems natural now that you don't mention it. :)

Comment: Not that there is anything particularly modular about PySide programming anyway.

Comment: @neuronet. Yeah, I don't think there's any magic bullet here. You have to re-connect the signal whenever a new editor is created. So you either have to pass a direct reference for the action to the delegate, or make the action accessible globally, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from a design point of view the top window is a sort of global.  You have already described a behaviour which is treating it in that way and (as ekhumoro has said) that pretty much requires you to provide access to that top window to the editor.

One very simple way to do that is to call `parent.window()` in the `createEditor` method.  Maybe something like:

```
parent.window().boldTextAction.triggered.connect(editor.toggleBold)
```

That seems to work for me.

Comment: Wow that's embarrassingly simple, and very instructive...I am working on understanding it. I have never used `QWidget.window()` before. The docs say that it returns the next ancestor widget that has (or could have) a window-system frame.' It looks like the parent of the editor is the parent of the `QStyledItemDelegate`, namely the `QTreeView`. (When I print the type of parent in createEditor, I just get  `QWidget` back). That would make the most sense, anyway. Then parent.window() would indeed return the main window, as we see.

Comment: Note sure how to find class name of parent object, just keeps returning QWidget, even when I print `parent.metaObject().className()`.  Wheras the same for the parent fed directly to QStyleItemDelegate returns the tree type...if you could clarify the nature of this parent that would be helpful.

Comment: I think the parent passed to createEditor is the QWidget that is displaying the item. I am not sure what type that QWidget is - it is created by the QTreeView - but it still makes sense to head up to its ancestor window. We could check the QTreeView code if you want but it's probably a custom QWidget within QTreeView.

Comment: Had a look but couldn't find it, sorry.

Comment: I started a separate topic on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938507/what-is-the-parent-of-createeditor-in-a-qstyleditemdelegate-pyside-pyqt-qt